# Use modreverseproxy only if cookie is found

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I have a site, lets call it example.com which is hosted on an Apache server listening in on port 80. I also am using `modproxy` at the moment to send traffic to another server that is listening in on port 8000. How can I only allow the traffic to be proxied if a `PHPSESSID` cookie is found? Here is my conf settings for the moment.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /private http://localhost:8000
    ProxyPassReverse /private http://localhost:8000/
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some other things that I am also trying are:

```
    <Proxy *>
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*PHPSESSID.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule /private http://localhost:8000/$1 [P,L]
```